# Why does "%d" can print out ASCII code not only decimal?

Tags: c, ascii

I heard that '%d' prints decimal, but if I import printf("%d",'a'), it prints out a ASCII code of 'a'. I cannot understand why %d which only can print out decimal also prints ASCII code. is ASCII code a decimal?

Comment: Character literals in C are just another way of writing the character code. `'a' == 95`

Comment: becuase you have told printf to expect a number, so it interprets 'a' as a number. https://www.asciitable.com/ you see 'a' is decimal 97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers do not know anything about "decimals". Compueters know **numbers**. Generally everything is a number in computers. Characters, strings - even machine code instructions.

Humans need numbers to be displayed in an understandable form. We are used to use base 10 numbers called by you "decimals".

Characters are numbers too. We (humans) have invented encodings to know what number represents a particular character. Very popular is ASCII system. When you `printf("%d\n", 'A');` then you simple print number representing character `'A'` using the base 10 representation.